# How can I find the corresponding .h file which includes the "cacheflush" function?

Tags: c, linux

I tried to use the cacheflush function in my Linux X86 computer.
However, while the man pages states that the function can be found in the ".h" files <sys/cachectl.h> <asm/cachectl.h> or <asm-generic/cachectl.h>, my GCC compiler cannot found these files.

What can I do? i.e., how can I include the function in my program so that GCC will recognize it?

Comment: Did you read the NOTES section of the man page?  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/cacheflush.2.html#NOTES

Comment: And specifically the "GCC alternative" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but read `man cacheflush`, I think you can't.

> Note: On some architectures, there is no glibc wrapper for this
> system call; see NOTES.
>
> **Architecture-specific variants**
> Glibc provides a wrapper for this system call, with the prototype
> shown in SYNOPSIS, for the following architectures: **ARC, CSKY,
> MIPS, and NIOS2.**
>
> On some other architectures, Linux provides this system call,
> with different arguments:
>
> M68K:
>
> ```
>   int cacheflush(unsigned long addr, int scope, int cache,
>                  unsigned long len);
> ```
>
> SH:
>
> ```
>   int cacheflush(unsigned long addr, unsigned long len, int op);
> ```
>
> NDS32:
>
> ```
>   int cacheflush(unsigned int start, unsigned int end, int cache);
> ```
>
> On the above architectures, glibc does not provide a wrapper for
> this system call; call it using syscall(2).

If I understand well, `glic` does only provide `cacheflush` for 4 architectures.

---

If you really want to call this function, `gcc` specifically provide `__builtin___clear_cache()` (look for it in man page), but again, that won't be portable to other compilers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply search for cacheflush functions in headers file with a grep :
`grep -rin cacheflush /usr/include`

Depending on your compiler, headers files can be located in `/opt/path/to/your/compiler`, check include path given to your linker.

Comment: simpler to type `man cacheflush`

Answer (score 0):

While it is not what I asked for- in Intel x86 one can flush invalidated pages using intrinsic intel commands, i.e., _mm_clflushopt and _mm_clflush.